# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation during a post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

Why I get *Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation during a post request*?

I made a `POST` request, put `formData` in it and set `processData` to `false`. What could be the error?

#### **Code:**

```
$(document).on("submit", "#reservation", function (e) {
    var csrftoken = $(this).find('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()

    e.preventDefault();
        $form = $(this);
        var form_data = new FormData($form[0]);
        
        $.post($form.attr('action'),{
            data: form_data,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
            },
        onAjaxSuccess
    );
    function onAjaxSuccess(data)
        {
          alert(data);
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `let` or `var` before your `$form` variable declaration, and the syntax for  the `$.post()` method seems a bit off. Try something like this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#reservation", function (e) {
    var csrftoken = $(this).find('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()

    e.preventDefault();
    let $form = $(this);
    var form_data = new FormData($form[0]);

    $.post($form.attr('action'), {
        data: form_data,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }).catch((err) => { console.error(err) }); // using es6 arrow function
})
```